# Learn Android Development (Have experience)

Tags: java, android

I have been developing for iOS for at least 3 years and have at least 1 year of experience for Java. For a long time I have been thinking to develop for Android but I do not know which book or course I should start. Any suggestions?

P.S I already downloaded Android SDK and eclipse.

Comment: Probably not a question that will survive on Stack Overflow, but http://www.apress.com/9781430239307

Comment: This is probably too subjective for SO. Google it or have a look on Amazon and decide for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Are you looking to get started with something for free or paid? If you are looking for something free try out the [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) page. If you're looking for something paid though, that is awesome, take a look at [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is the best video tutorial to start with

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL33384E9848C4F55E

Comment: Thanks! I will start right away.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the following android developer site.

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html